# Read/Write OpenCL memory buffers on multiple GPU in a single context

Tags: memory-management, opencl, gpu

Assume a system with two distinct GPUs, but from the same vendor so they can be accessed from a single OpenCL Platform. Given the following *simplified* OpenCL code:

```
float* someRawData;

cl_device_id gpu1 = clGetDeviceIDs(0,...);
cl_device_id gpu2 = clGetDeviceIDs(1,...);
cl_context ctx = clCreateContext(gpu1,gpu2,...);

cl_command_queue queue1 = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx,gpu1,...);
cl_command_queue queue2 = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx,gpu2,...);

cl_mem gpuMem = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, ...);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue1,gpuMem,...,someRawData,...);
clFinish(queue1);
```

At the end of the execution, will `someRawData` be on both GPU in-memory or will it be only on `gpu1` in-memory?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the host data will only be copied to gpu1... I'm not sure if space would be allocated on both devices. The spec is not very helpful here. I have a system with two GPUs at work -- I'll try to give it a shot tomorrow if I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the implementation, where the data will be after calling `clFinish()` but most likely it will be on the GPU referenced by the queue. Also, this kind of abstraction makes it possible to access `gpuMem` from a kernel launched on `queue2` without an explicit data transfer.